# Orchard settings resetting when debugging

Tags: orchardcms

Posted this on codeplex, but thought I'd try here as well.

I've created an Orchard application, which I've deployed to Azure, however when debugging it, it occasionally resets everything so that I have to enter the site details (i.e. site name, admin user, database, etc.) again. Because I'm using an existing database, it ends up duplicating various things, so I end up with multiple admin users, multiple navigation menus, etc. Why is this happening, and is there a way I can prevent it?

Comment: Are you using local Azure storage?

Comment: UseDevelopmentStorage=true, yeah. At least it should be. I have a ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg, which I assume it will use when debugging. Sorry, a bit new to Azure.

Comment: make sure you are not shutting down azure local storage while you are debugging,check for any such condition

Comment: Hmm, but what about when I need to shut it down, e.g. shutting down my machine?

Comment: do you experience this problem when you restart your machine?

Comment: I'm not too sure what causes it. I *think* it happens after I run ClickToBuildAzure, but I'm not certain. I think I have restarted my machine and it's been ok before, but again, I'm not certain.

Comment: i guess ClickToBuildAzure is resetting settings,just try once again to make sure

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22450/discussion-between-cris-and-tom)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the cause, as detailed here:

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/428980

It's to do with the unit tests that are run in ClickToBuildAzurePackage. If I comment them out from AzurePackage.proj, it works.